# How do I write a compound query in firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following typescript for looking up a city based on its population ...

```
import { getFirebase } from "react-redux-firebase";

...

  get fb() {
    return getFirebase();
  }
  get fs() {
    return this.fb.firestore();
  }

  getCollection(collectionName: string) {
    return this.fs.collection(collectionName);
  }
...
firestore.collection("cities").where("population", "<", 100000)
```

What if I wanted to add a clause to look up a city by its population AND restrict the state to California?  (My state column is called "CA")?

Comment: Firestore doesn't have columns - it has fields.  Are you saying you have a field called "CA" with some value?  What is that value that you want to filter on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working with the data as shown in the [documentation on compound queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries), then just add another where clause, which creates a logical AND condition:

```
firestore
    .collection("cities")
    .where("population", "<", 100000)
    .where("state", "==", "CA")
```